# Git Reset master / Copy code from a branch to master

Tags: git

How can I delete or reset my remote and local Git master branch and copy/use the code of another branch to master ?

I want to preserve this another "better_branch" and make an exact copy from it to master !
The old commits on the actual master branch are not that important!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `master` branch, you can simply run

```
$ git reset --hard better_branch
```

Then `git push -f` to "force push" your local `master` overtop of the remote `master`.

Comment: Thanks, that saves my day!